# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/fop/apps/FopFactory;

Tags: java, apache, apache-fop

I 've used  apache FOP 2.0 jar and below code

```
  FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File("."));
```

and getting below error So what is the reason and solution on it?
I've also used xmlgraphics-commons 1.5

but of no use

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/apache/fop/apps/FopFactory;
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1083)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:640)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());
```

Comment: thanks. Tried this also but not working. Giving same error